# RuntimeError: Node '__v2libuid__Plus502__v2libname__Plus225' (Plus operation): DataFor: FrameRange's dynamic axis is inconsistent with matrix

Tags: cntk

the same training code that works on one machine gets the following error on a different machine.  The first machine is a SurfaceBook, the other is my desktop with a GTX 1080.  Any idea what's going wrong here?

The error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "MultitaskAtis.py", line 162, in 
>       trainer_intent.train_minibatch(mb)
>     File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py34\lib\site-packages\cntk\trainer.py", line 90, in train_minibatch
>       updated = super(Trainer, self).train_minibatch(arguments, device)
>     File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py34\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 1768, in train_minibatch
>       return _cntk_py.Trainer_train_minibatch(self, *args)
>   RuntimeError: Node '__v2libuid__Plus502__v2libname__Plus225' (Plus operation): DataFor: FrameRange's dynamic axis is inconsistent with matrix: {numTimeSteps:1, numParallelSequences:14, sequences:[{seqId:0, s:0, begin:0, end:1}, {seqId:1, s:1, begin:0, end:1}, {seqId:2, s:2, begin:0, end:1}, {seqId:3, s:3, begin:0, end:1}, {seqId:4, s:4, begin:0, end:1}, {seqId:5, s:5, begin:0, end:1}, {seqId:6, s:6, begin:0, end:1}, {seqId:7, s:7, begin:0, end:1}, {seqId:8, s:8, begin:0, end:1}, {seqId:9, s:9, begin:0, end:1}, {seqId:10, s:10, begin:0, end:1}, {seqId:11, s:11, begin:0, end:1}, {seqId:12, s:12, begin:0, end:1}, {seqId:13, s:13, begin:0, end:1}]} vs. {numTimeSteps:23, numParallelSequences:11, sequences:[{seqId:0, s:0, begin:0, end:16}, {seqId:1, s:1, begin:0, end:10}, {seqId:2, s:1, begin:10, end:21}, {seqId:3, s:2, begin:0, end:15}, {seqId:4, s:3, begin:0, end:23}, {seqId:5, s:4, begin:0, end:11}, {seqId:6, s:5, begin:0, end:14}, {seqId:7, s:6, begin:0, end:14}, {seqId:8, s:4, begin:11, end:22}, {seqId:9, s:7, begin:0, end:11}, {seqId:10, s:8, begin:0, end:14}, {seqId:11, s:9, begin:...

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be a bug with respect to GPU memory usage in the two device. Assuming you are able to run the code well on CPU device on both Surface book and Desktop.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more? how do you know it's memory usage? From the error message, I would have expected it to be to do with data sizes.